# Problems with recursive algorithms and Spark DataFrames

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If you want to do anything interesting with Graphs -- whether with `GraphX` or the new `GraphFrames` -- you end up doing recursive algorithms. The problem I am having is that when using `DataFrames` each iteration of the algorithm takes longer and longer, and more execution stages get kicked off per iteration. I'm more of a functional Spark user -- I can make things happen but don't have a full grasp of what happens under the hood. But my guess is that the lineage chain keeps extending, and without breaking the lineage chain, the earlier iterations get re-calculated with each step. So iteration 1 does iteration 1; iteration 2 does iteration 1 again, then iteration 2; iteration 3 has to do 1, then 2 again, etc.

So my first question: Is that really what's happening, more or less?

To test it, I've been playing with `RDD.checkpoint`. It seems to help, but I can't really prove it. So that's my second question -- tell me if the way I use `checkpoint` is helping or not.

Lastly, it would be great to hear about other possible solutions. Maybe Spark isn't even the right answer. I'm open to anything.

To test all of this, I have been using a simple algorithm to polyfill vertex attributes -- a sort of attribute inheritance. Given a graph like this:

```
val nodes = Seq(
    (1L, Option(1L), Option(1L)),
    (2L, None, Option(2L)),
    (3L, Option(2L), None),
    (4L, None, None)
).toDF("id","inputType","recurrence")

val edges = Seq(
    (1L, 2L, "parent"),
    (2L, 4L, "parent"),
    (1L, 3L, "parent")
).toDF("src","dst","type")
```

Once I polyfill missing attributes in the vertices, I should get something like this:

```
+---+---------+----------+
| id|inputType|recurrence|
+---+---------+----------+
|  1|        1|         1|
|  2|        1|         2|
|  3|        2|         1|
|  4|        1|         2|
+---+---------+----------+
```

Vertex `1L` is the parent, and the other vertices have inherited missing attributes from the parent, following the chain upwards if needed.

The algorithm actually isn't very complicated -- I'm going to use my own cobbled-together DataFrame / Graph algorithms instead of `GraphFrames`.

First, I'll define a function to create edge triplets out of nodes and edges:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def triplets(vertices: DataFrame, edges: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  edges.toDF(edges.columns.map(c => "edge_" + c):_*)
    .join(vertices.toDF(vertices.columns.map(c => "src_" + c):_*), col("edge_src") === col("src_id"))
    .join(vertices.toDF(vertices.columns.map(c => "dst_" + c):_*), col("edge_dst") === col("dst_id"))
}
```

Based on the data above, `triplets(nodes,edges)` shows:

```
+--------+--------+---------+------+-------------+--------------+------+-------------+--------------+
|edge_src|edge_dst|edge_type|src_id|src_inputType|src_recurrence|dst_id|dst_inputType|dst_recurrence|
+--------+--------+---------+------+-------------+--------------+------+-------------+--------------+
|       1|       2|   parent|     1|            1|             1|     2|         null|             2|
|       1|       3|   parent|     1|            1|             1|     3|            2|          null|
|       2|       4|   parent|     2|         null|             2|     4|         null|          null|
+--------+--------+---------+------+-------------+--------------+------+-------------+--------------+
```

So far so good, now a recursive function to polyfill `null` values down the hierarchy:

```
def fillVertices(vertices: DataFrame, edges: DataFrame) : (DataFrame, DataFrame) = {
  val vertexAttributes = vertices.columns.filter(c => c != "id")
  val edgeAttributes = edges.columns.filter(c => (c != "src" && c != "dst"))

  val messages = triplets(vertices,edges).select(
    Seq(col("edge_src"), col("edge_dst")) ++ vertexAttributes.map(attr => when(col("src_" + attr).isNotNull && col("dst_" + attr).isNull, col("src_" + attr)) as "msg_" + attr):_*
  ).filter(
    vertexAttributes.map(attr => col("msg_" + attr).isNotNull).fold(lit(false)){ (a,b) => a || b }
  ).groupBy(col("edge_dst") as "msg_dst")
   .agg(max(col("msg_" + vertexAttributes(0))) as ("msg_" + vertexAttributes(0)), vertexAttributes.slice(1,vertexAttributes.length).map(c => max(col("msg_" + c)) as ("msg_" + c)):_*)

  if (! messages.rdd.isEmpty) {
    val newVerts = vertices.join(messages, col("id") === col("msg_dst"), "left_outer").select(Seq(col("id")) ++ vertexAttributes.map(c => coalesce(col(c), col("msg_" + c)) as c):_*)
    fillVertices(newVerts, edges)
  }
  else (vertices,edges)
}
```

If you do `fillVertices(nodes,edges)._1.show` it will indeed show the correct results -- all the nodes have their `null` values correctly populated. However, it takes a ridiculous amount of computational stages.

Again note that this is very similar behavior to what I have seen with `GraphFrames` -- I don't think it's specific to what I am doing, but rather a general problem with recursive algorithms in Spark.

Like I said, I have tried checkpointing the underlying `RDD` and it seems to help. I use this to checkpoint a `DataFrame`:

```
sc.setCheckpointDir("/your/checkpoint/dir")
def dfCheckpoint(df: DataFrame) : DataFrame = {
  df.rdd.checkpoint
  if (df.rdd.count > 0) {
    df.sqlContext.createDataFrame(df.rdd, df.schema)
  }
  else df
}
```

Then to test it side by side, here's the same algorithm as above, except that the newly created node `DataFrame` gets checkpointed before it is returned.

```
def fillVerticesCheckpoint(vertices: DataFrame, edges: DataFrame) : (DataFrame, DataFrame) = {
  val vertexAttributes = vertices.columns.filter(c => c != "id")
  val edgeAttributes = edges.columns.filter(c => (c != "src" && c != "dst"))

  val messages = triplets(vertices, edges).select(
    Seq(col("edge_src"), col("edge_dst")) ++ vertexAttributes.map(attr => when(col("src_" + attr).isNotNull && col("dst_" + attr).isNull, col("src_" + attr)) as "msg_" + attr):_*
  ).filter(
    vertexAttributes.map(attr => col("msg_" + attr).isNotNull).fold(lit(false)){ (a,b) => a || b }
  ).groupBy(col("edge_dst") as "msg_dst")
   .agg(max(col("msg_" + vertexAttributes(0))) as ("msg_" + vertexAttributes(0)), vertexAttributes.slice(1,vertexAttributes.length).map(c => max(col("msg_" + c)) as ("msg_" + c)):_*)

  if (! messages.rdd.isEmpty) {
    val newVerts = vertices.join(messages, col("id") === col("msg_dst"), "left_outer").select(Seq(col("id")) ++ vertexAttributes.map(c => coalesce(col(c), col("msg_" + c)) as c):_*)
    fillVerticesCheckpoint(dfCheckpoint(newVerts), edges)
  }
  else (vertices, edges)
}
```

Now if you do `fillVerticesCheckpoint(nodes,edges)._1.show` it completes a lot faster. There seem to be a lot fewer stages. I don't know how to quantify it, but it seems like the checkpoint version has 1/3 the number of stages as the non checkpointed.

Based on what I'm seeing, then, I'm guessing the answer to my first question is, yes, this is a lineage issue. The answer to my second question seems to be yes, checkpointing makes it better. But it would be great to have confirmation on these two.

As to my last point, other ways to solve the same problem, the only think I can think of is to essentially create my own checkpoint by saving `DataFrames` to `Parquet` files between each iteration. Anybody got anything else?

Comment: Have you tried the `localCheckpoint` version we talked about?

Comment: Didn't help. Still takes 25 seconds to solve even a simple graph that takes only 3 iterations of Pregel.